# javascript - search for string in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, ecmascript-6

I would like to search for a string in array of objects and returns objects that matches. Trying to use `es6` here.

Please find below code:

```js
// set of keys
const defConfigs = [{
    title: "Id",
    key: "id"
  },
  {
    title: "Tenant",
    key: "tenant"
  },
  {
    title: "Opened",
    key: "opened"
  },
  {
    title: "Title",
    key: "title"
  },
  {
    title: "Status",
    key: "status"
  },
  {
    title: "Priority",
    key: "priority"
  }
];

// items as array of objects
const items = [{
    id: "INC000000004519",
    title: "Follow-up after INC000000004507",
    description: null,
    urgency: "4-Low",
    severity: "4-Minor/Localized"
  },
  {
    id: "INC000000004515",
    title: "network drop:↵Network Element CVU042_Johnstown get unsynchronized↵Network Element CVU043_Redman",
    description: "Client network drop since 08:51 until 09:06, pleas…ork Element CVU045_North_Salem get unsynchronized",
    urgency: "3-Medium",
    severity: "3-Moderate/Limited"
  },
  {
    id: "INC000000004088",
    title: "not able to schedule GPEH in ABC",
    description: "Contact: abc@xyz.com↵+14692669295↵…WCDMA, we are not able to schedule GPEH in ABC. I",
    urgency: "4-Low",
    severity: "4-Minor/Localized"
  },
  {
    id: "INC000000004512",
    title: "SR Updated - P3 - 2018-0427-0305 - xyz TELECOMMUNICATIONS ROMANIA S.R.L - Lost the  mng connect",
    description: null,
    urgency: "4-Low",
    severity: "4-Minor/Localized"
  },
  {
    id: "INC000000004414",
    title: "Acme incident 1 title",
    description: "Acme incident 1 description",
    urgency: "2-High",
    severity: "1-Extensive/Widespread"
  }
];


// trying to search for string in keys defined in defConfigs
items.filter(item =>
  defConfigs.forEach((def) => {
    if (def.key in item) {
      return (item[def.key].toString().toLowerCase().match('low').length > 1);
    }
  }));

// always throws an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
console.log(items);
```

Here, there are 3 objects with string "low" and I expect the code to return the first item (where the "title" is "Fol**low**-up after"); but `match` never returns.

**How do I search for a string in array of objects and return those objects as a result ?**

Comment: `.match('low').length` will throw if no match is found. Also note that `def.key in item` is false for all of your examples.

Comment: You could use a `foreach` loop and stringify each object is the array. The do  a regex `match str.match('low')`. If it returns true then return that item

Comment: Isn't it supposed to return ***one*** item? Two items contain low but in urgency category.

Comment: yes exactly. 'low' is in  urgency category which isn't in `defConfig`. But string 'low' is there in `title` in one of the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely you will notice that:

1. You do not check if `.match` matched (it returns `null` on no match; testing for `null.length` will throw an error)
2. You are checking `match.length > 1`... the syntax you are using will return an array with exactly one item or null
3. You are missing the return statement for `.filter`
4. You do not assign the return value of `.filter` to any variable

Here is what you need to do:

```
var filteredItems = items.filter(function (item) {
    return defConfigs.some(function (def) {
        return (def.key in item)
            ? item[def.key].toString().toLowerCase().match('low') !== null
            : false;
    });
});
console.log(filteredItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function will return `null` if there are no matches, therefore you need check this case. Next you could use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function to verify that at least one item in array is fulfilling your condition. For example:

```
items.filter(item =>
  // check if at least one key from `defConfigs` on `item` matches 'low'
  defConfigs.some((def) => {
    if (def.key in item) {
      const matched = item[def.key].toString().toLowerCase().match('low')
      // return true if item matched
      return !!matched
   }
   // match not found by default
   return false
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.prototype.match()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) will return null when no match found. You should strictly compare match result to null if you want it to work.

You should take a look at [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It returns a new array and won't modify the reference passed as argument, your original items are safe (for now).

Answer (score 0):

The word "low" is found only in the **urgency** attribute and your **defConfigs** array don't have this field
So after you add it to the array do the following :

```
let newItems=items.filter(item => {


    let count= defConfigs.reduce((acc, def) => {

        if (def.key in item) {
            let arr = item[def.key].toString().toLowerCase().match(/low/gi)
            return acc + (arr ? 1 : 0);
        }
        else {

            return acc;
        }
    }, 0)

    return count >0
});

console.log(newItems);
```

- So first define a new variable for the filtered data **newItems**
- Then i used the **reduce** function to get if there is any match in the whole object
- lastly used the regular expression **/low/gi** in the match function

Comment: Correct. Tried to modify code but SO doesn't allow.

Comment: if my solution helped you solve the problem, please mark it as solved

Comment: 'low' is in urgency category which isn't in defConfig. But string 'low' is there in title in one of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, `if (def.key in item)`, it will check if the value of `def.key` is equal to the name of an attribute in item. To accomplish what you were thinking of doing, see the comments in the code below:

```
// set of keys
const defConfigs = [{title: "Id", key: "id"},
{title: "Tenant", key: "tenant"},
{title: "Opened", key: "opened"},
{title: "Title", key: "title"},
{title: "Status", key: "status"},
{title: "Priority", key: "priority"}];

// items as array of objects
const items = [{id: "INC000000004519", title: "Follow-up after INC000000004507", description: null, urgency: "4-Low", severity: "4-Minor/Localized"},
{id: "INC000000004515", title: "network drop:↵Network Element CVU042_Johnstown get unsynchronized↵Network Element CVU043_Redman", description: "Client network drop since 08:51 until 09:06, pleas…ork Element CVU045_North_Salem get unsynchronized", urgency: "3-Medium", severity: "3-Moderate/Limited"},
{id: "INC000000004088", title: "not able to schedule GPEH in ABC", description: "Contact: abc@xyz.com↵+14692669295↵…WCDMA, we are not able to schedule GPEH in ABC. I", urgency: "4-Low", severity: "4-Minor/Localized"},
{id: "INC000000004512", title: "SR Updated - P3 - 2018-0427-0305 - xyz TELECOMMUNICATIONS ROMANIA S.R.L - Lost the  mng connect", description: null, urgency: "4-Low", severity: "4-Minor/Localized"},
{id: "INC000000004414", title: "Acme incident 1 title", description: "Acme incident 1 description", urgency: "2-High", severity: "1-Extensive/Widespread"}];


// trying to search for string in keys defined in defConfigs
items.filter(item =>
defConfigs.forEach((def) => {
  //iterate through all attributes in the object
  for(var key in item){
    //check if the attribute exists, if it has the method 'indexOf' (if it's a string), and that it has def.key in the string
    if (item[key] && item[key].indexOf && item[key].indexOf(def.key)!= -1) {
      //match only accepts regular expressions which are signified in JS by enclosing the expression with forward slashes
      return (item[def.key].toString().toLowerCase().match(/low/).length >1);
    }
   }
}));
```